# EllipticE in maple compared to matematica and python

Tags: python, math, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration, maple

Trying to implement Euler Elastica in maple where Jacobi elliptic functions and Elliptic Integration is vital.
The Jacobi elliptic functions: JacobiSN, JacobiCN, JacobiDN, and JacobiAM seems to work as I would expect, but Elliptic Integration: EllipticE behaves inacurate to what I would think it should do.

Have made a comparison between maple, matematica and python buildin function:

```
Maple: 
plot([t, EllipticE(t), t = 0 .. 1])
```

[image]

```
Matematica: 
plot[EllipticE[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Python(scipy.special):     
t = arange(0, 1, 0.001)
plot(t, ellipe(t))
```

[image]

The only thing that I could find was that:
Maple calculate the Incomplete and complete elliptic integrals of the second kind.

Where python and matematica calculate the complete elliptic integrals of the second kind

Answer (score 2):

Love and hade when I realise the answer 4 min after posting the question.
maple use m where python and matematica uses k. where k^2 = m

```
plot([t, EllipticE(sqrt(t)), t = 0 .. 1])
```

[image]